# Setting overflow scroll without bottom scroll

Tags: html, css

How do you set the overflow scroll without the bottom scroll?

I only need to show the side scroll for the wrapper of the content.

Comment: Thank u all for your valuable comments.. Its working!!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will show only vertical scrollbar.

```
#element {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

OR:

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers support

```
overflow-x: visible|hidden|auto|scroll;
overflow-y: visible|hidden|auto|scroll;
```